# hide a block which is visible and show the next one

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a very simple carousel where there is only one switch which on click hides a div which is visible and shows the next one. If I simplify this its a carousel which only moves in one direction with a single trigger

Here is how i am approaching this

```
var lists = $('.listItem');
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i+=3) {
  lists.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<li class='new'><ul></ul></li>");
}

$('.toggleClass').click(function(){
    if($('.new').is(':visible')){
        //hide the one which is visible and show the next one
        //run this in a loop
    };
});
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/6KS3a/2/

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved my own problem

This did it

```
$('.new').eq(0).addClass('current');
//$('.new').eq(10).addClass('last');

$('.toggleClass').click(function(){
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
    .next().show().addClass('current');
});
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/6KS3a/5/